# What is an engineering term for this type of arm

Tags: mechanical-engineering, cad

I'm trying to describe a part -  it's an arm that holds an axle sleeve (which ultimately holds a wheel). I'm stuck right now describing it simply as a "wheel arm", but was wondering if there was some better, more engineering-appropriate term.   I'd appreciate any feedback. Thanks[image: ![wheel arm?]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zpDA.png)

Comment: A shaft is one possible term, or axle shaft.

Comment: Part naming, or non-naming is a big issue in mechanical engineering data management. See you can not reuse a part if you cant search for it. But then giving a name for every thingmabob is quite hard, especially if you assume group B would also guess to name it the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I’m thinking, based on what I see and what you describe, something like:

“Adjustable Axle Carrier (Arm)” (or Bracket)

It’s not too long of a name yet provides some detail while using some basic terms which represent its purpose. Limit the jargon unless it’s necessary or the context of the design or assembly warrants it.

Answer (score 0):

The circular rod? Could be something like;

- Cantilever support arm/axle
- Support arm
- Wheel support arm/axle

Something along those lines would probably be descriptive enough, in my opinion.

Comment: I think he's asking about the sheet metal part that hangs on the circular rod, and contains the axle sleeve. Looks like it's designed to slide front/rear on the rod, and the sleeve moves up/down in the mystery part, providing adjustment of the wheel position in 2 axes. This sort of thing is common on manual wheelchairs to help adjust the balance point.